# Performance of big slabs due to allocation, initialization and deallocation overhead costs [C++11]

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

I have found in running performance analysis of various string classes, that the allocation, initialization and deallocation overhead costs due to fine-grained allocators more tuned for thread globals, scales very badly.

A wonderful example of one of these fine grained allocators is Makalu, and the paper describes in great detail how that is done:
[Makalu: Fast Recoverable Allocation of Non-volatile Memory](https://cpb-us-e1.wpmucdn.com/blogs.rice.edu/dist/5/7236/files/2016/09/oopsla2016-copyright-1s0zst5.pdf)

This kind of use of thread globals for caching deallocated items to avoid context switches is a great thing, but not for all programs.

I have a graph for the a comparison of `std::string` and three types of strings I have constructed that are faster: `Direct`, `Symbiont` and `Head`, that compares the allocation, initialization and deallocation overhead costs (ADIDOC, for short) for sorting these strings in simple arrays using slab allocation on the stack.

The `std::string` class has a head with a pointer to the tail that is copy-on-write (COW) in C++11 (that COW is changing, I think in a future release, but the extra fine-grained allocation will remain, I'm sure.) The heads of `std::string` are allocated in a single slab array, but the tails are all allocated fine-grained at various locations in the memory pool.

The three other classes are all allocated as a single slab array, with no fine-grained allocation, whatsoever. Here are three graphs for that overhead in the process of creating initializing and deallocating 8-byte, 128-byte and 1024=byte strings for sorting (the sorting costs are measured separately and are analyzed in another posting).

NOTES:

1. All of the performance data presented is run on release builds, OF COURSE.
2. All slabs are allocated on the stack as automatic variables in code blocks which deallocate the memory in between these runs in one process execution. So the stack pointer moves up some gigabytes and then back down.
3. Were this all done in a `mmap`, one would start the process and do the `mmap` with the `MAP_POPULATE` flag before doing any runs, to level the playing field. Since this is on the stack, an attempt is made to accomplish the same thing by allocating a huge array and writing to the end of it, and that seems to set up all the memory allocation overhead (page table entry/PTE allocation and TLB miss overhead) for the subsequent runs during the process. See the slides from hotstorage 2017, for details at: 
   [Efficient Memory Mapped File I/O for In-Memory File Systems](https://www.usenix.org/sites/default/files/conference/protected-files/hotstorage17_slides_choi.pdf)
4. The `SortBench.cpp` program used measures different strings and containers against identical template sort code: all strings and containers experience the same number of compares and swaps and run fast or slow depending on the underlying physics of those strings and containers. Sorting is just a method for seeing the scalability of strings and containers.
5. For these measurements, the sorting numbers don't matter, because it's the setup for sorting and the exit after sorting that is being measured. For the record in each set of runs, the Direct strings are executed first and would take the memory allocation hit, and `std::string`s are executed last, as is seen in the data files.

[Quick sort allocation, initialization and deallocation overhead costs (ADIDOC) for 8-byte strings](https://github.com/charlesone/Kaldanes/blob/master/Quick%20Sort%20Array%20Overhead%20Costs%20(Allocation%20%2B%20Default%20Initialization%20%2B%20Deallocation)%20For%208-Byte%20Strings.jpg)

[Quick sort ADIDOC for 128-byte strings](https://github.com/charlesone/Kaldanes/blob/master/Quick%20Sort%20Array%20Overhead%20Costs%20For%20128-Byte%20Strings.jpg)

[Quick sort ADIDOC for 1024-byte strings](https://github.com/charlesone/Kaldanes/blob/master/Quick%20Sort%20Array%20Overhead%20Costs%20For%201024-Byte%20Strings.jpg)

The allocation, initialization and deallocation overhead cost measurements were all done using the nanosecond timer. The code for `SortBench.cpp` is located in the GitHub:
[Kaldanes R&D] (https://github.com/charlesone/Kaldanes)

The first issue we notice is, this appears to scale very well for one of them. The blue line is the Direct string class, which is just a block of string bytes in a struct as an array element. That is the one class that has no initialization at all, just storing the string. After it reaches the scale of 128,000 8-byte strings (1MB) the overhead cost is scaling arbitrarily flat. Is that the operating system slab allocator at work? That was my working hypothesis, but I don't think that's where the fairy dust is being applied, it seems like the kernel is doing something special for massive objects.

The second issue is that at the last point of 134,217,728 8-byte strings (after which `std::string` [yellow line] runs out of memory on my 15GB machine, from only storing 1GB of string data,) the `std::string` class is 5 orders of magnitude worse than the best slab-allocated class with no initialization.

If the Direct strings use of the slab allocator remains flat at the terabyte level that would make for an eight order of magnitude difference. And another three at the petabyte scale makes an eight orders of magnitude difference (308 days, nearly a year). Using 7400 cores in parallel might bring that down to an hour, while slab allocation, if flat at that scale would remain at 1/10 of a millisecond in one core. This needs to be tested at scale on a Gen-Z or Intel XPoint system. I would presume (but have not tested) that the memory with no file backing version of mmap (presumably with flags `MAP_NORESERVE` and `MAP_POPULATE`) would have the same performance benefits.

My question is about the C++ runtime and the kernel, why is this kind of enormous allocation so arbitrarily fast, and at what size does it stop being constant time?

Here's the architecture info:

[charles@localhost ~]$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 58
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               1989.132
CPU max MHz:           3800.0000
CPU min MHz:           1600.0000
BogoMIPS:              6784.92
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts

Makefile flags: 
CPPFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Ofast 
CXXFLAGS = -Wall

gcc/g++ 4.8.5 on Centos-7 Kernel info:
[charles@localhost]$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 14 21:49:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: operating system, kernel, architecture, compiler, compiler options?

Comment: See the Makefile in the GitHub, too many flags to list here. Also the file processor.info.txt has hardware. gcc/g++ 4.8.5 on Centos-7 recently updated kernel.

Comment: The main difference I see is that Direct has a trivial default constructor while the others don't.

Comment: @Charlie... "see the Makefile in GitHub" sorry but no. You question should stand on its own. You shouldn't have to check external resources to get vital information about your question. If you feel the flags are too many, list only the ones that are relevant for your question, e.g. c++ standard and flags controlling architecture & optimization. [edit] your question to include the information you provided in the comment about the compiler version. "recently updated kernel" Since this question deals specifically with how kernel behaves you could be specific and post the exact kernel version.

Comment: That's a big chunk of it. But why flat for all that memory?